# Why Kendo Dropdownlist is not working on chrome for android?

Tags: android, asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, drop-down-menu, kendo-ui

I'am using Kendo for asp.net MVC to have dropdownlist on a website. It's working fine on PC browsers and Firefox on Android 9. But it is not working on Chrome v72.0.3626.105 (and even Opera) for android 9. When I click I have the list of items that drops down but clicking an item is not selecting it and the dropdownlist is back to its initial state. I wonder if someone has faced this case.
The code I use is simple

```
//c# code
@(
    Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(x => x)
        .BindTo(Model)
        .ValuePrimitive(true)
        .Name(name)
        .Events(e => {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(onSelect))
                e.Select(onSelect);
        })        
)
```

the code for the select event handler is simple:

```
//js code
function onSelect(e) {
        window.location.href = e.dataItem.Value;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that I miss some files that seem to be required by chormium based browsers:

```
kendo.fx.min.js
kendo.userevents.min.js
kendo.mobile.scroller.min.js
```

Answer (score 0):

I used a later version of the kendo.js and it solved the problem (v2019.1.220).